# Build and Run works but Publish not

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a problem when I try to publish my project:

> "Copying file Scripts\peity\bin\update_docs to
>   obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Scripts\peity\bin\update_docs
>   failed. Could not find file 'Scripts\peity\bin\update_docs'."

It's strange, because I can build all the 5 projects and I can run on localhost fine. But when I try to publish, the message appears in the output window and the status is "Publish Failed".

I don't know if this has some relevance, but I'm use VS2015 and the person who sent me this solution used VS 2017.

Comment: Does your bin folder have a file called `update_docs` ? Is this file destroyed/recreated at compile time? Navigate to this folder and look for the missing file while you rebuild the solution. Is it there at all? You may need to change the build options for this particular file so it is copied to output directory.

Comment: i have the folder "ProjectUI\Scripts\peity\bin" but i don't have the update_docs folder inside. I create the folder inside and the error change to
"Copying file Scripts\peity\bin\update_docs to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Scripts\peity\bin\update_docs failed. Access to the path 'Scripts\peity\bin\update_docs' is denied."

Comment: Did you create the folder in your project explorer or windows explorer? You can manually give your service account permissions to the folder (this may be your logged in account), or if you create it in the project explorer it should automatically inherit those permissions.

Comment: I open the Scripts\peity\bin Folder in the Solution Explorer delete the update_docs file.... i'm don't knew but update_docs is a file, not a filder.
Thanks for help